# Create nested OU's from variable

Tags: powershell

Currently I have these as variable:

```
$domain = 'DC=test, DC=local'
$OUarray = "IDM",
"IDM/Accounts",
"IDM/Accounts/Deleted",
"IDM/Accounts/External",
"IDM/Accounts/Service",
"IDM/Accounts/Service/Service - No Sync",
"IDM/Accounts/Service/Service - Sync",
"IDM/Accounts/Users",
"IDM/Groups",
"IDM/Groups/Application",
"IDM/Groups/Control",
"IDM/Groups/Roles",
"IDM/Groups/Security",
"IDM/Mail/Contacts",
"IDM/Mail/Distribution Groups",
"IDM/Mail/Resource Mailboxes",
"IDM/Mail/Shared Mailbox"
```

Then what is the best way to create those OU's I cant use a csv file to store the ou's that need to be created.

I have a foreach:

```
Foreach ($I in $OUarray)
{
   
}
```

And I think I need to split all those lines but when I use the .split command it puts everytyhing on a new line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched for a solution? There is a search bar at the top of each site on SO. ;-)  I'd start with creating one OU first and extend the code step by step.

Comment: You can use the variable content as a CSV. You don't need a physical one. Creating an OU hierarchy is the same, no matter what automation language or GUI you'd use. There are lots of examples of creating nested AD OU's all over the web, via the GUI and PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

```
($objects = @'
OUPath
"IDM",
"IDM/Accounts",
"IDM/Accounts/Deleted",
...
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv)
```

From that point, just use it as a normal CSV.

> ['powershell create nested ou'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershell%20create%20nested%20ou%20&form=ANNTH1&refig=a1c92d1ed7a94e58a28e98bb4ae381d6&sp=-1&ghc=1&pq=powershellcreate%20nested%20ou%20&sc=2-27&qs=n&sk=&cvid=a1c92d1ed7a94e58a28e98bb4ae381d6)
>
> https://dimitri.janczak.net/2016/04/20/recursive-ou-creation-with-powershell
>
> TechNet Create Active Directory Users and add to Nested OUs:
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Create-Active-Directory-6efa0451
>
> Script Create OU Structure in Active Directory:
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-OU-Structure-in-ab5bfe83